# how can I forward all calls except one?

Tags: google-apps

because i have a small business I get lots of calls, but sometimes I want a day off... so on these days I would like to be able to forward all my calls to my office, BUT allow ONLY my office number to call me in case of an emergency...

so how can I forward all incoming calls to my phone, but exempt a single number so as to allow it to be able to ring thru to my phone?

does the phone have this capability, or is it possible with an app?   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For starters, call forwarding happens at your service provider, not at your phone. For most services, to forward calls that you don’t answer, first dial *71+the 10-digit number to forward calls to. To turn off call forwarding dial *73.

Now, step two. Do a search on the play store for “white list”. There are a number of apps that will only allow the numbers that you have entered into the white list. In theory, all others will get forwarded. I haven’t tested it but it should work. Good Luck.